# Performance testing of ASP.NET Web page - request limit set to 10

Tags: asp.net

In order to test how many async request can be handled at the same time, I've created a sample console application that showers my web application with requests:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string url = "http://localhost/cip/AsyncPage.aspx";

        ThreadStart del = delegate
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting request");
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine("Response ready");
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            new Thread(del).Start();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

AsyncPage.aspx is an Async="true" page and contains a task that loops from 1 to 10, every iteration sleeps for 1 second and writes to response dummy data (so single request takes 10 seconds).

What I've noticed that responses are returned in a batch of 10. So after 10 seconds I get 10 responses, after next 10 seconds, I get next 10 responses. I've done similar testing with Fiddler and result was the same - 10 requests seem to use all .... ASP.NET resources?

I wonder which ASP.NET setting is responsible for this behaviour.

Comment: Can you make a test, to set on the page `EnableSessionState="false"` and make one more test to see if what I say have a point in your case, or is some other browser limitations, the browser that you use to make the calls.

Comment: Just did it, see my comment on your answer :)

Comment: Ok, now I read it, so this is not the case, I remove my answer. Then is probably some other limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local load testing on a consumer platform is not an option in this instance.

It's not ASP.NET that has request limits, it's IIS itself and it depends on which version of Windows you're running. Essentially, you're restricted to a maximum of 10 unless you're on a Server platform.

If you really want to load test this, the best idea would be to run it on a real server, you can probably virtualise to get what you need, although you obviously wouldn't get real-world results from a virtualised server.

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc268241.aspx

Comment: So considering my machine configuration: Windows 7 Ultimate + IIS 7.5 , can I change this limit or I should test it on Server platform (which I don't have at home :/ )

Comment: Like that link says, the limit is only removed in Server platforms. You could always download the Virtual Server and VHD of Windows Server 2008/2012? It's a 180 day evaluation, so should be more than good enough for testing :)

Comment: Also the real purpose of this testing is just to play around with configuration and learning

Comment: Virtual Server and VHD of Windows Server 2008/2012? I need to upgrade my PC first :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This hard limit of ten connections on workstation versions of windows for Microsoft software  dates to 1993/4.

From one person's perspective, Here is the reason which apparently drove the limitation.    Up until that point (93/94) the adoption of Windows NT in the enterprise was being driven by two items, Microsoft SQL Server and Microsoft SNA Server.  Both of these solutions ran just fine on Workstation versions of Windows even in non-Microsoft environments ( Banyan | Novell | Generic IP ).  Beginning with SQL Svr 4.21 and the similar dated SNA Server release Microsoft changed the server code base to allow only 10 connections when running on Windows workstation editions.  Not surprisingly NT Server adoption went through the roof as organizations had to purchase server editions to underpin existing servers to achieve the same level of functionality as prior to the update.   Microsoft marketing made tons of market foo about the enormous rates of NT server adoption...of course they left out the part that Microsoft forced the adoption by changing the code of the SQL/SNA servers which required an update to NT Server from people who had been just fine with NT Workstation as their core OS under their server.

This limit applies only to Microsoft software running on Microsoft platforms.   So, if you place Apache for Windows or ORACLE for Windows on the same workstation version of Windows then you are no longer limited to only ten connections.   You may thank Redmond for their decisions which are positively impacting your technical life.